# Give users same permissions to multiple tables in single a operation?

Tags: sql-server-2008

In SQL Server Management Studio, is there any way to configure the same set of permissions on multiple tables in a single step? For example, I need to assign select permissions for a single login to 21 different tables.

Currently, I do this by going into security properties for the user, adding the tables to the security window, and then selecting the appropriate permission(s) on each table one by one. In situations where the permissions are indentical, these are a lot of error-prone, repetative steps.

Comment: You probably want to look into [roles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189121.aspx "Database-Level Roles").

Answer (score 0):

You can use `GRANT` and `DENY` to set permissions for a login. You can programatically do it with dynamic SQL or you can copy paste a bunch of lines only changing the table name (Object name) for example.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187965(v=sql.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187965%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188338(v=sql.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188338%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)

```
GRANT EXEC ON dbo.MyStoredProcedure to 'myUser'
```